# Laravel 5.0 switching from default database to another to use on all views and controllers

Tags: database, laravel, connection

well I have a problem when it comes to switch databases.
I have a database "A" set up as default on the config.database file; besides that I have in connections array a database "B".

```
'default' => "A",
```

....

```
    'connections' => [

        'A' => [
             'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        ],

        'B' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => env('DB_HOST_1', 'localhost'),
            'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE_1', 'forge'),
            'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME_1', 'forge'),
            'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD_1', ''),
       ],
.....
```

when I log in and go to POST login method in controller, I switched to database "B"

```
\Config::set('database.default', "B");
```

to use the 'User' table and get credentials to log in.

```
if(\Auth::attempt(array('username'=>$username , 'password'=>$password) ) )...
```

which it works fine. HOWEVER, when I go to a different blade.php 
I will get the credentials from the "USER" table located on default connection ("A") instead of USER table located in B

So when I do

```
echo Auth::user()->firstName()." - ".Auth::user()->id; 
//it will display  Carlos - 10 instead of displaying Luis - 10
```

So I guess it is looking for the row where id=10 but on table A(dafault connection) instead of B (one I switched using Config::set()...

I have tried also putting Config::set('database.default', "B") on each view, but it still gives me the credentials from table A
any help?
how can i change the database permanently?
by the way, why do I have to call 2 databases for user credentials? well because on my login form I have an input to enter company name (A or B).

Comment: Do you also mean a new request when you say new view?

Comment: oh I meant when I successfully log in            `if(\Auth::attempt(array('username'=>$username , 'password'=>$password) ) )
         {
          
                return view('test');

         }
`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the connection like this:

```
DB::setDefaultConnection('A');
```

Comment: I just added that to my login controller, but no luck. I am using eloquent by the way.  I just noticed it works if I go to   `APP > user.php`   and change `protected $table = 'User';` to protected `$table = 'B.User';` inside the USER class, but how to change that from LoginController?